# MinGW unresolved reference when linking with Visual Studio generated static library

Tags: visual-studio, mingw

Using gcc 4.5.0 under MinGW, I am trying to build a Windows console executable which links to a static library created with Visual Studio. The static library seems to have dependencies on Visual studio symbols which aren't available under MinGW. Error messages:

```
undefined reference to `_ftol2_sse'
undefined reference to `_allmul'
```

Is there a replacement for these functions under MinGW or can this by fixed by setting an additional linker flag?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a real static library built with msvc and not an import library to a dll correct? If that's the case, wouldn't there be issues with a difference of ABI between MinGW and msvc?

Comment: Yes, it's a real static library.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to explicitly link with the right version of the MSVC runtime. GCC defaults to a different version.

Comment: How do I do that (I am not a MinGW expert)?

Comment: Usually by including the (absolute or relative path to) the dlls on the gcc invocation.

Comment: I tried linking to the following alternate runtime libraries msvcr70 msvcr71 msvcr80 msvcr90, but the error does not go away.